# How to change Doctrine "findBy/findOneBy" functions's behaviors to reduce the number of queries?

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a Symfony2 using Doctrine.
I would like to know how to change the behavior of "findBy" functions when retrieving my entities.

For example, if you call "findAll()", it returns all products.

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:Product')->findAll();
```

However, how to reduce the number of queries, because, by default, it will create a new query each time I want to get a member linked to a join column. So if I get 100 entities, it will process 101 queries (1 to get all entities and 1 by entity to get join column).
So today, I use createQuery() function by specifying the joins. Is there a way to configure something about findBy functions to skip createQuery method ?

Thanks in advance !

K4

Comment: Create a join in your Repository ? `$qb->addSelect('foo'); $qb->leftJoin('product.foo', 'foo')`?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch out this in below way

```
 public function findUser() {
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
                ->createQuery('SELECT us.id as id, us.name as user_name FROM Bundle:User us');
        try {
            return $query->getResult();
        } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```